# Azure App Service & SQL Server have different locations

Tags: xamarin, azure-sql-database, azure-app-service-plans

When creating my Azure App Service I used the default South Central US location but when I made my SQL server I set it to Central Canada. Will this still work properly or do I have to remake the Service Plan?
According to [Develop Cloud Connected Mobile Apps with Xamarin and Microsoft](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter1/firstapp_pc/) it says to make them have the same location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work, but it will DEFINITELY slow things down. A lot. I highly recommend moving your App Service to Central Canada or your mySQL instance to South Central US.

Comment: Is there a way to do either without deleting and making a new Mobile App Service??

Comment: Not to my knowledge - someone please correct me if I'm wrong. You might find it easier to move your database.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. But the performance may slow down. It depends on the load on the server. If this is a test service, use the current configuration if the worker service changes according to the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Answering pretty old question but if that helps anyone else, you do not have to remake the Service Plan, you can move your SQL Database region easily by following MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-sql)